# ReactJS API data wont Load - Broken Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

New to reactjs and having issues.  So the `useEffect` does an axios request to get the id from the API,  once we have this another API is called to get the data of that user.

The website seems to launch before the data comes back.  I read up on await, promise and obviously doing something wrong.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
export default function UserDashboard() {
const config = {
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Accept':'application/json'
    }
}
const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
const [orgEvents, setOrgEvents] = useState([]);
const [orgID, setOrgID] = useState('')
const [nameList, setNameList] = useState([]);
const navigate = useNavigate
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
    getData();    
}, []);

const loadData = async () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/userDashboard')
    .then(res => {
       if(res.data.valid) {
            setAPIData(res.data);
            setOrgID(res.data.userID);        
        }
        else {
           navigate('/login')
        }
    }) 
   .catch(err => console.log(err))   
   }  
   console.log(APIData);
   console.log(orgID);
   const dataDB = { organizer_id: orgID };
   const timeout = { timeout: 8000}
   const getData = async () => {
       axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/getOrgEvents', dataDB, timeout, { config })
       .then(getData => {
          setOrgEvents(getData.data);
        })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
   }
```

Comment: The app will load without waiting for the async calls, you can display something like "Loading..." in your page while you wait for the data to be loaded.

Comment: Also, if `getData()` depends on the response of `loadData()`, you have to synchronize them by declaring the `useEffect()`'s callback as `async` and using `await` before the calls to the two data functions.